# http form post change submit data

Tags: c#

```
<FORM id=loginForm name=loginForm method=post 
          action="http://www.example.com/login.php">
<INPUT name=username>
<INPUT name=password>
<INPUT type=submit value="Log In" name=action_login>
</FORM>
```

Is there any way of changing name=action_login to name=action_signup and post username and password to http://www.example.com/signup.php

in the server site it has name=action_login but I would like to change this on the client side and not touch the server site.

Comment: you can change it with javascript ps you should really follow the proper markup, i.e. all attributes should be quotes in double quotes and `input` should be self-closed

Comment: Why does this have "cross site scripting" written all over it?  I'm trying to think of a use case for doing this but I can't.

Comment: You have this tagged as C# (and WinForms, which I removed).  Are you using a server-side technology -- WebForms or MVC or something else?  You need to provide more information.

Comment: [scibuff] - can you please give a little example code     

[chris-lively] - is no cross site scripting.            

[david-hoerster] - basic im verry new to this c# programming, i know it's c# sharp im using visual studio it says windows form application under c# language. thats what I have choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FireFox, get the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon which lets you modify markup in real-time.

Chrome has a built-in similar tool.

Right click -> Inspect Element

Comment: I would like to do this in my c# windows form application code if possible.