# How to make the browser login and do something then re-login with another account

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, autocomplete, webbrowser-control

I have a simple program that i can open a webpage and i paste the user name and password from textbox1

then do something inside, after that a want to re-login with another account

i can do it for tow or three accounts put i want to deal with an open number of  usernames

i want to take usernames from a **Multiline textbox**

the code to paste only the first line and the pass word and click ok  is:

```
TextReader read = new StringReader(textBox2.Text);
int rows = 500;

string[] text1 = new string[rows];
for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
{    
    text1[r] = read.ReadLine();
    // textBox3.Text = text1[r];

    HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name"); if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = text1[r];

    ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password"); if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = text1[r] + "5";

    ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("s1"); if (ele != null)
    ele.InvokeMember("click");
```

`text1[r]` means that it will take the just the first line

now the program is inside then  logout with this code

```
webbrowser1.navigate("http://example.com/logout.php");
```

then i want to re login and do the same put with the second line (another account) then the third etc. How can i do it?

Comment: You know this does read kind of like you're trying to write a brute force password hacker - I'm sure you wouldn't do that would you?

Comment: Nah sure he's taken an ethics course.

Comment: It's a legitimate programming question. I'm suspecting that he has a LONG time before he's able to hack/brute force anything :). He'll get shut down for DOS attacking way before he's able to get through the password list.

Comment: the accounts will not be more than 50 ones  thats it  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't quite work like that. What you need to do is behave like the browsers, namely, submit the form:

- [How do you programmatically fill in a form and 'POST' a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857/how-do-you-programmatically-fill-in-a-form-and-post-a-web-page)
- [How to submit http form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273998/how-to-submit-http-form-using-c-sharp)

You will have to study the structure of the POST request and build a similar post request with your application. You'll have to use something like [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) to investigate the network traffic that's generated when you submit the form and duplicate the POST request. Take a look at this question too: [http form post change submit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741599/http-form-post-change-submit-data)