# make a loop inside string[]?

Tags: c#, string, loops, browser

i have got a multiline textBox1 and webbrowser1

when the the document complete, i want the program to fill an element with one line then do something then refill the same element with the second line etc............

the code  is:

```
       HtmlEleme ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("element ID");
       if(ele != null)
                ele.InnerText = textBox1.Lines[0];
```

how could i make this   ( for    while or.....) and how???

and where i should put the code ?

Comment: So what do you mean by doing something after filling an element?

Comment: No tags in the title please. Furthermore: exactly what are you trying to do? Show us an example of how an element should look like before and after it has been "processed" by your code.

Comment: do something is : click a button or change a element value

Comment: and for the tags i am soooory

Comment: i have asked this question in another way but they told me i am a hacker the real question is here:

Comment: No problem about the tag, I was just informing you and I removed it... but update your question with the details we asked for. You can click on the edit button, make your changes and submit again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786547/how-to-make-the-browser-login-and-do-something-then-re-login-with-another-accoun

Comment: Ok, I'll answer your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser will load page when you click the button you can follow this:

```
 bool loaded;
void Operate()
{
            string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                loaded = false;
                HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("element ID");
                ele.InnerText = lines[i];
                //click a button here
                HtmlElement elmbutton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ButtonID");
                elmbutton.InvokeMember("click");
                //here wait for web browser navigate.
                while (!loaded)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                   Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }

        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            loaded = true;
        }
```

On the other hand I must warn you about the drawbacks of `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: but there is some thing wrong with
            "   loaded    "

Comment: the prog work with out errors but nothing happend when i run it

Comment: You should assign "buttonID" before click